# How to remove multiple spaces and characters from a XML files using regex with python?

Tags: python, xml

I have hundreds of lines in an XML file like these two examples:

```
<settings site_id="someID123" xmltv_id="Some text - dummy (2) HH">Some text - dummy (2) HH</settings>
<settings site_id="moreID321" xmltv_id="More Text">More Text</settings>
```

I want to format with python regex everything inside of xmltv_id="**HERE**" without spaces, dashes or parentheses and add at the end **.xx**

```
xmltv_id="Some text - dummy (2) HH"
xmltv_id="More Text"
```

become like this

```
xmltv_id="Sometextdummy2HH.xx"
xmltv_id="MoreText.xx"
```

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Can't you better do it with xpath?

Comment: thanks for your reply, I can do it with any tool that solve my issue. Just let's me know how to do it then I will try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I parse XML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python)

Comment: @tres.14159 although that post is about parse XML in Python doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex never be a robust and suitable approach when parsing structured data, such as XML/HTML.
Use appropriate parsers.

with [`etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module and [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html?highlight=re%20sub#re.sub) function:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

root = ET.parse('yourxml.xml').getroot()
pat = re.compile(r'[\s()-]+')    # regex character class for chars to replace

for el in root.findall('settings[@xmltv_id]'):
    el.set("xmltv_id", pat.sub('', el.get("xmltv_id")) + '.xx')

ET.dump(root)
```

Sample output:

```
<main>
  <settings site_id="someID123" xmltv_id="Sometextdummy2HH.xx">Some text - dummy (2) HH</settings>
  <settings site_id="moreID321" xmltv_id="MoreText.xx">More Text</settings>
</main>
```

---

You may easily save the resulting elementTree into a new file with https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following approach - read & parse xml, modify data, write xml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('1.xml')

for element in tree.findall('settings'):
    element.set('xmltv_id', element.get('xmltv_id').replace(' ', ''))

tree.write('2.xml')
```

Original xml `1.xml`:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    <settings site_id="someID123" xmltv_id="Some text - dummy (2) HH">Some text - dummy (2) HH</settings>
</note>
```

Modified xml `2.xml`:

```
<note>
    <to>Tove</to>
    <from>Jani</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
    <settings site_id="someID123" xmltv_id="Sometext-dummy(2)HH">Some text - dummy (2) HH</settings>
</note>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can accomplish this with a single regex in python. A solution I can think of is something like this:

```py
import re

def format_line(line):
    m = re.search('(.*xmltv_id=")(.*)(".*)', line)
    stripped_tag = re.sub(' |-|\(|\)','', m.group(2))
    return f'{m.group(1)}{stripped_tag}.xx{m.group(3)}'
```

```py
>>> format_line('<settings site_id="someID123" xmltv_id="Some text - dummy (2) HH">Some text - dummy (2) HH</settings>')
'<settings site_id="someID123" xmltv_id="Sometextdummy2HH.xx">Some text - dummy (2) HH</settings>'
```

Answer (score -1):

With [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is:

```
import re

xmltv_id1="Some text - dummy (2) HH"
xmltv_id2="More Text"

replace_regex = r'\s|[-]|[(]|[)]'

print(re.sub(replace_regex, '', xmltv_id1) + '.xx'))
print(re.sub(replace_regex, '', xmltv_id2) + '.xx'))
```

Comment: Well, it is a answer, it is not a free job for someone. The next steps are easy with [lxml](https://lxml.de/) for example.

Comment: The next steps have nothing to do with your current stepts.. You need to to start from the correct attributes 'xmltv_id', which you are ignoring completely

Comment: Maybe you can check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912434/how-do-i-parse-xml-in-python

Comment: That answer focuses on a specific tag/attribute... which you do not.

Comment: In Spain there was a old website, it named RinconDelVago. this website had a lot of school works and the people only copied the work and did nonething. Do you want a free work or only a solution and you will add the code for your bussines?